# how to build generic sum of python function results

Tags: python, python-2.7

I would like to build the sum of functions in python. However, I don't know upfront the length of the sum. All functions are of similar type, i.e. having one input and same output type. For two something like this would work

```
In [180]: def H(f, g):
     ...:     def _h(x):
     ...:         return f(x) + g(x)
     ...:     return _h
```

However, I would like to have something which is generic in the sense that I could write `H(*args)` and it returns me the sum of all function in `args` (also working for just one).

Am I correct that this is the only way to build sum of functions? I can't write something like `h = f+g` for two function ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is probably easier to write something that is extendable. And you should use the built-in function `sum` to do the actual summing. This returns a [generator](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators) that applies each function to the input x:

```
def map_funcs(x, *funcs):
    return (f(x) for f in funcs)

funcs = lambda x: x + 1, lambda x: x**2
x = 10
print(sum(map_funcs(x, *funcs)))
```

If you want to you can also make it a wrapper which returns something callable, similar to what you've already got:

```
def map_funcs(*funcs):
    def wrapper(x):
        return (f(x) for f in funcs)
    return wrapper

funcs = lambda x: x + 1, lambda x: x**2
x = 10
print(sum(map_funcs(*funcs)(x)))
# 111
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible. You have to use the `sum()` builtin function that return the sum of all values in the given list. Before that, you of course have to compute the list of all the functions givent to `H()` run with the correct parameter:

```
def power_two(x):
    return x**2

def plus_20(x):
    return x + 20

def H(*args):

    def _h(x):
        _results = [f(x) for f in args]
        return sum(_results)

    return _h

if __name__ == '__main__':

    the_func = H(power_two, plus_20)
    final_result = the_func(2)

    print("(2^2) + (2+20) = %s" % the_func(2))
    print("(3^2) + (3+20) = %s" % the_func(3))
```

Returns:

```
(2^2) + (2+20) = 26
(3^2) + (3+20) = 32
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

```
def H(*args):
    def _h(x):
      for func in args:
          z += func(x)
      return z
    return _h
```

Just loop around the functional arguments and then sum it. I guess simple?
I hope it helps!